# how to handle user interaction of external commands in scala

Tags: scala, testing, cucumber, command-line-interface, integration

I have a delete script that deletes data and while doing so prompts to ask for proceed. I want to pass both my command and the user interaction "Y" in cucumber-cli

```
sys.process.Process("abc delete #>> Y", new java.io.File(getProjectPath)).!
```

I have tried

- `echo Y | abc delete`
- `abc delete <<< Y`
- `printf Y | abc delete`

But none seems to work inside scala-cucumber. It works only on terminal.
What could be the problem?

That's my O/p

```
  Press 'Y' to continue...
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException: Console has reached end of input
    at scala.io.StdIn$class.readChar(StdIn.scala:93)
    at scala.io.StdIn$.readChar(StdIn.scala:229)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what cucumber-cli is, but this might help you:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream

val inputString = "y"
val is = new ByteArrayInputStream(inputString.getBytes("UTF-8"))
val process = Process("abc delete") #< is
process.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

("echo Y" #> edhCommand).! worked